# Cooldown for a certain command in bash

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

I am writing a shell script (#!/bin/sh) on my RPI that sends emails whenever a sensor measures above a certain degree celsuis.

Since the sensors get triggered every minute for logging, a temperature above 30 degrees for about an hour would resolve in 60 mails, which is not what i want.

Is there a way to set a cooldown for the command that sends the mail?

Here is the code that checks the sensor data and sends mails if above 30 degrees (its solved with functions but i think thats irrelevant):

```
if [ $tempC -ge 40 ]
then
  #logging code
  mailSend "WARNING: Temperature is currently: $temp and Humidity is: ${file#"sensor_dhtH"}" #This command needs a cooldown
elif [ $tempC -ge 30 ]
then
  #logging code
  mailSend "Attention: Temperature is currently: $temp and Humidity is: ${file#"sensor_dhtH"}" #This command needs a cooldown
else
  #logging code
fi
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Easy. Whenever you actually send a mail, save a variable recording the time of last mail, e.g. `tolm=$SECONDS` Then, whenever you are about to send a new mail calculate `((elapsed=SECONDS-tolm))` and don't send it unless `elapsed` is greater than some threshold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, thanks to **@Mark Setchell** i was able to get to this solution:

```
limit=$((2*60*60)) #limit is 2 hours

if [ $SECONDS -ge $limit ] #if seconds-since-last-send greater or equal to your-set-limit(here 2h)
then
#send the mail
SECONDS=0 #set the seconds-since-last-send to 0
else
echo "not yet ma man, wait some seconds" #not sending the mail cuz its too early to send another
fi
```

I didn't know about the **$SECONDS** variable that counts itself up before, so that defenetly was helpful, thanks :)

Comment: $SECONDS only exists in bash tho, if someone has a solution that also works in sh, that would be great!